# Log source file and line numbers

Tags: debugging, logging, rust

Using Rust's `log`, and `env_logger` crates, how do I have the output include the source file and line number where a log call was invoked?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the following example `logger_example` is the name of my binary in `Cargo.toml`, e.g.

```
[[bin]]
name = "logger_example"
path = "src/bin/logger_example.rs"
```

You can custom-format the logger like this:

```rs
use log::{info, LevelFilter};
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    env_logger::Builder::new()
        .format(|buf, record| {
            writeln!(
                buf,
                "{}:{} {} [{}] - {}",
                record.file().unwrap_or("unknown"),
                record.line().unwrap_or(0),
                chrono::Local::now().format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
                record.level(),
                record.args()
            )
        })
        .filter(Some("logger_example"), LevelFilter::Debug)
        .init();

    info!("hello world")
}
```

The output is:

```
src/bin/logger_example.rs:20 2020-11-30T19:34:16 [INFO] - hello world
```

I found the answer here: https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/development_tools/debugging/config_log.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to add on top of this and retain the color coding as it is available in the native env_logger?

Comment: @VikasGoel have a look at [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b502962abc877ed8fa1f298d6a4dbc8). You can use the style struct from env_logger crate

Comment: You can filter all log messages (not just ones from your code) with: `.filter(None, log::LevelFilter::Info)`.

Comment: @Coder the color is controled by style, https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/fmt/struct.Style.html

Answer (score 0):

log::Record has `file` and `line` methods. You have to check the configuration of env_logger to see if there's built-in support for these, otherwise you might have to configure a custom formatter and hand-roll it.