# rust slog printing invocation location (source file name and line number)

Tags: rust

I am using slog 2.7. I am looking for a way to print the source file location of the log statement.
An example using env_logger is provided here:
[Log source file and line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810740/log-source-file-and-line-numbers)

My current slog configuration function is provided below

```rust
pub fn configure_log(log_file_name: &str) -> slog::Logger {
    println!(
        "'{}' at configure_log(), log_file_name is:'{}'",
        chrono::prelude::Utc::now(),
        log_file_name
    );
    let log_file_path = std::path::Path::new(log_file_name);
    let dir_file_path = log_file_path.parent().unwrap();
    std::fs::create_dir_all(dir_file_path).unwrap();

    let log_file_handler_option = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
            .create(true)
            .write(true)
            .truncate(true)
            .open(log_file_name)
            //.unwrap()
        ;
    let log_file_handler = match log_file_handler_option {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{}", e);
            panic!();
        }
    };

    let decorator = slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build();
    let my_log_drain = slog_term::FullFormat::new(decorator).build().fuse();
    let my_log_drain = slog_envlogger::new(my_log_drain);
    //let my_log_drain = slog_async::Async::new(my_log_drain).build().fuse();
    let my_log_drain = slog_async::Async::new(
        slog::Duplicate::new(
            slog::Filter::new(
                slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(log_file_handler))
                    .build(),
                |record: &slog::Record| record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Warning),
            ), //,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout())).build()
            slog::Duplicate::new(
                slog::Filter::new(
                    slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(
                        std::io::stderr(),
                    ))
                    .build(),
                    |record: &slog::Record| record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Warning),
                ), //,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout())).build()
                slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build()).build(),
            ),
        )
        .fuse(),
    )
    .build()
    .fuse();

    slog::Logger::root(
        my_log_drain,
        slog::o!("n" => env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),"v" => env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")),
    )
}
```

Comment: [`use_file_location`](https://docs.rs/slog-term/2.8.0/slog_term/struct.FullFormatBuilder.html#method.use_file_location)?

Comment: @ Jmb how can I use make use of use_file_location in the above example?

Comment: According to the docs, should be `let my_log_drain = slog_term::FullFormat::new(decorator).use_file_location().build().fuse();`

Comment: @ Jmb Thank you very much, interestingly I had already done so but I failed to see that the file name and location were being printed till I a minute ago. Your advise led me to solve this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @ Jmb below is the edited version of the code that solves the question I had asked.

```
    pub fn configure_log(log_file_name: &str) -> slog::Logger {
        println!(
            "'{}' at configure_log(), log_file_name is:'{}'",
            chrono::prelude::Utc::now(),
            log_file_name
        );
        let log_file_path = std::path::Path::new(log_file_name);
        let dir_file_path = log_file_path.parent().unwrap();
        std::fs::create_dir_all(dir_file_path).unwrap();
    
        let log_file_handler_option = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
                .create(true)
                .write(true)
                .truncate(true)
                .open(log_file_name)
                //.unwrap()
            ;
        let log_file_handler = match log_file_handler_option {
            Ok(f) => f,
            Err(err) => {
                println!("{:?}", err);
                panic!("Unable to open the log file '{}', '{:?}'",log_file_name,err);
            }
        };
    
        let decorator = slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build();
        let my_log_drain = slog_term::FullFormat::new(decorator).build().fuse();
        let my_log_drain = slog_envlogger::new(my_log_drain);
        //let my_log_drain = slog_async::Async::new(my_log_drain).build().fuse();
        let my_log_drain = slog_async::Async::new(
            slog::Duplicate::new(
                slog::Filter::new(
                    slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(log_file_handler))
                        .use_file_location()
                        .build(),
                    |record: &slog::Record| record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Warning),
                ), //,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout())).build()
                slog::Duplicate::new(
                    slog::Filter::new(
                        slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(
                            std::io::stderr(),
                        ))
                        .use_file_location()
                        .build(),
                        |record: &slog::Record| record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Warning),
                    ), //,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout())).build()
                    slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build()).use_file_location().build(),
                ),
            )
            .fuse(),
        )
        .build()
        .fuse();
    
        slog::Logger::root(
            my_log_drain,
            slog::o!("n" => env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),"v" => env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")),
        )
    }
```